# In windows phone,Messagebox caption only can show less than two lines?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, messagebox

```
    public static MessageBoxResult Show(
    string messageBoxText,
    string caption,
    MessageBoxButton button
)
```

use below code to show a messagebox
**The problem is**
If the caption is too long,the messagebox will not display well
Like this[image]

I have tried to use some symbol like “\n”,but it doesn't work,can't change to 3 lines
**Is there a 2 lines limit in windows phone messagebox caption?**
And would u help me to solve this problem?
**Thanks ,Any advice will be great!!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that MessageBox.Show() is not really that *Developer Friendly*. You can use **CustomMessageBox**, which is in the Toolkit currently. 
You could find further details [here](http://shawnoster.com/2012/10/welcome-custommessagebox-to-the-windows-phone-toolkit/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Aju, or you could also create your own custom control, exactly like message box, if you don't wan't to install 3-rd party libraries

Answer (score 0):

```
 You could implement customize messageBox like this.
Put this code in .xaml and make changes accordingly
   <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Collapsed" Name="stkMessage">
                <Border.Background >
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/LoderBackground.png" />
                </Border.Background>
                <StackPanel  Height="200" Width="480" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#B0C4DE">               
                    <StackPanel Height="130" Width="460">
                        <TextBlock Name="txtMessage" Text="abc..." Foreground="#1c1c1c" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontFamily="/Font/BKANT.TTF#Book Antiqua" Margin="20,40,20,20"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Height="70">
                        <Button x:Name="btnOk" Background="#123C8E" Height="70" Padding="0" Content="OK" Width="150" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" Click="btnOk_Click_1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#123C8E" FontFamily="/Font/BKANT.TTF#Book Antiqua" >

                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>

Put this code in .cs

 private void btnOk_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtMessage.Text = "";
            stkMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```